# A code to take an amount of others in a string of lines

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Before I begin, I would include this link to the problem in a word document, with highlighted texts, so the problem would be much clearer

---

https://archive.org/download/batfile10112019/bat%20file%2010112019.rar

---

```
*0000000000003000345800483854651180013732112019              0
*000000000010004466170000003000083BOUBADJA SAFIA             1
*000000000010010346810000003110730BOUKHEMKHEM NABILA         1
*000000000010010694160000000000806ROUIBAH MESSAOUDA          1
*000000000010014708210000000000999SETILA AFAF                1
*000000000010024010600000003176161ZAITER EP BOUHAROUD SOUAD  1
*000000000010054726551524653176161BOULASSEL NORA             1
```

Let’s suppose I have the above text file that contains lines, the length of each line is 62 (a combination of characters and spaces, you could verify by placing the cursor before the « * » character and count till the last character). I want to keep the header as it is, but for the other lines, I want a batch file (`.bat`) that will do the following :

1. Keep the header as it is ( as I mentioned above).
2. It will take 10.00 (unit of money, whether it’s euro, dollar etc…) out of each amount in the lines, the amount of each line begins from position « 22 » to position « 34 », so the amount of :

   - The second line is : 30000.83
   - The third line is : 31107.30
   - The fourth line is : 8.06
   - The fifth line is : 9.99
   - The sixth line is : 31761.61
   - The seventh line is : 15246531761.61

We can’t take 10.00 (dollars or euro or whatever…) out of the amounts of the fourth and the fifth lines which are 8.06 and 9.99 respectively, so the batch file will keep them as they are.
But for the amounts of the second, third, sixth and the seventh line will be changed as follows:

- The second line is : 29990.83
- The third line is : 31097.30
- The fourth line is : 8.06
- The fifth line is : 9.99
- The sixth line is : 31751.61
- The seventh line is : 15246531751.61

So the output file will look like this :

```
*0000000000003000345800483854651180013732112019              0
*000000000010004466170000002999083BOUBADJA SAFIA             1
*000000000010010346810000003109730BOUKHEMKHEM NABILA         1
*000000000010010694160000000000806ROUIBAH MESSAOUDA          1
*000000000010014708210000000000999SETILA AFAF                1
*000000000010024010600000003175161ZAITER EP BOUHAROUD SOUAD  1
*000000000010054726551524653175161BOULASSEL NORA             1
```

I have another problem when I deal with larger text file (15000 lines)

A friend helped me, but there were some errors in the code, that's why i included the above link in a word document to see the error message when dealing with text files that contain more than 10000 lines.

the code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
chcp 28591 >nul

set nouveau=modified.txt

echo. > %nouveau%


for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("original file.txt") do (

    set "line=%%A"
    set "index=!line:~-1!"

    if !index! EQU 1 (
        set "account=!line:~0,21!"
        set "amount=!line:~21,13!"
        set "number=!line:~21,9!"
        set "cut=!line:~30,4!"
        set "client=!line:~34!

        call :zeros amount

        if !amount! GEQ 1000 (
            set /a cut=!cut!-1000
            set cut=000!cut!
            set cut=!cut:~-4!
        )
        echo.!account!!number!!!cut!!client!

    ) else (echo.!line!)

) >> %nouveau%

exit


:zeros

set "chaine=!%1!"

for /L %%E in (0,1,12) do (
    if not "!chaine:~%%E,1!"=="0" (set "%1=!chaine:~%%E!" & goto :eof)
)

goto :eof
```

I hope that I can take any amount I want from any line
(10.00 in this example).
If I want to change it to 5.00, is it possible to change simply the value 10.00 to 5.00 in the provided code.
thanks in advance for any help from you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code is not just wrong, but also very inefficient... In order to perform the subtraction using the 9-digits limit of `set /A` command, you may split the operation in two parts: the low order (right side) 7 digits of the number plus the high part (left side) remaining 6 digits. The result is a pure Batch file that should run fast even over a file 15000 lines long.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem "subtract" may have maximum 7 digits including two decimal digits
set "subtract=1000"
set "nouveau=modified.txt"

set "subtract=0000000%subtract%"
set "subtract=1%subtract:~-7%"

set /P "header=" < "original file.txt"

(
echo %header%

for /F "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%A in ("original file.txt") do (

   set "line=%%A"
   set "high=1!line:~21,6!" & set "low=1!line:~27,7!"

   set /A "lowN=low-subtract" 
   if !lowN! geq 0 (
      set /A "low=10000000+lowN"
   ) else (
      set /A "highN=high-1000001"
      if !highN! geq 0 (
         set /A "high=1000000+highN, low=20000000+lowN"
      )
   )

   echo !line:~0,21!!high:~1!!low:~1!!line:~34!

)

) > "%nouveau%"
```

Comment: I take my hat off to you Aacini, ( for 11 digits and two decimals, it seems it doesn't work?)

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your comment... The code work for numbers with 11 integer digits and two decimals, but the amount to subtract  (the subtracting part) can only have 5 integer digits and 2 decimals _in the current version_. Of course, it is possible to modify the program in order to subtract an amount of 11 integer digits and 2 decimals, but the code would be more complex... However, a modification for 7 integer digits and 2 decimals (9 total digits) would be very simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aacini

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical flaw (using the last four digits only for calculation). Probably you did this to work around the INT32 limit of `set /a`, but it will cause false results in some cases. You have to calculate with the whole amount. As `cmd` isn't able to do this, use the help of another language (I chose PowerShell here). The downside is poor performance because PowerShell has to be loaded for each calculation.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
chcp 28591 >nul

set nouveau=modified.txt
break> %nouveau%

(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("original file.txt") do (
  set "line=%%A"
  set "index=!line:~-1!"
  if !index! EQU 1 (
    set "account=!line:~0,21!"
    set "amount=!line:~21,13!"
    set "client=!line:~34!
    REM strip leading zeros:
    for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%a in ("!amount!") do set cut=%%a
    if !cut! geq 1000 (
      for /f %%b in ('powershell "if (!cut! -ge 1000) {!cut!-1000} else {!cut!}"') do set "cut=0000000000000%%b"
      set cut=!cut:~-13!
    ) else set cut=!amount!
    echo !account!!cut!!client!
  ) 
))>"%nouveau%" 

goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephan, a slow performance, but it worked anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using powershell, then you could probably just use a simple `.ps1` script:

```bat
$Minus = 10.00
$LineNo = 1
Get-Content ".\original file.txt" | ForEach {
    If ($LineNo -Eq 1) {$_} ElseIf ($LineNo -GT 1) {
        [Decimal]$Decimal = $_.Substring(21,11)+"."+$_.Substring(32,2)
        If ($Decimal-$Minus -LT 0) {$Result = $_.Substring(21,13)} Else {
            $Result = (100*($Decimal-$Minus)).ToString("0000000000000")}
        $_.SubString(0,21)+$Result+$_.SubString(34)}
    $LineNo++} | Set-Content ".\modified.txt"
```

Just adjust `$Minus` as necessary.

*Note: `Get-Content` may not be the quickest method to use if your files are very large.*

Comment: thanks a lot Compo, it worked as i wished... thanks sir, problem is solved